# List comprehension doesn't eliminate duplicates

Tags: python

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

new_list = []
new_list.append([num for num in a+b if num not in new_list])

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Why does this code produce duplicates, instead of just a list of all numbers with no duplicates like `set()` would?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> new_list = []
> new_list.append([num for num in a+b if num not in new_list])
> ```

A couple things prevent this from working.

1. To add the elements of one list to another use `extend` not `append`. `append` appends the *entire list* to the input list, rather than adding the individual elements.
2. Even if you change it to `extend`, all of the items in the list comprehension are generated before they're added to `new_list`. They wouldn't be added one by one, so the `not in new_list` check won't see the items from previous iterations. It'll be checking against an empty `new_list`.

This idiom really only works as an explicit loop. I presume you started with something like this:

```
new_list = []
for num in a+b:
    if num not in new_list:
        new_list.append(num)
```

This type of loop doesn't convert well to a list comprehension because it has a self-dependency. The loop depends on the results of previous iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a list comprehension, but strictly for the side-effects of executing it:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

new_list = []
[new_list.append(num) for num in a+b if num not in new_list]

print(new_list)  # -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

If you don't like building a list that's immediately thrown away, here's an alternative that uses a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and the built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function to consume it:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

new_list = []
any((new_list.append(num) for num in a+b if num not in new_list))

print(new_list)  # -> [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work is you used extend instead of append and an iterator instead of a list as the parameter:

```
new_list.extend(num for num in a+b if num not in new_list)
```

By using an iterator as the parameter, the content of new_list is updated as you go so the condition in the comprehension can access the content of the list so far.  When you have a list as a parameter, the whole parameter gets evaluated before new_list is updated so new_list remains empty during the comprehension and the condition never finds previous elements (which are not added yet)

Note that this is an inefficient way to skip duplicate values because, as the list gets filled, checking for an existing value takes longer and longer resulting in an O(n^2) time complexity.  You should use a set instead of a list.